# recarregar efeitos do material design

Tags: javascript, ajax, async, xmlhttprequest, material-design

Tenho um site com material design, porém quando atualizo o html da página com XHR o novo conteúdo perde o efeito do javascript como eu poderia fazer para recarregar o mdl?

Para fazer a mudança entre as view, uso duas funções, na primeira passo a url do arquivo, o id do elemento que vai conter o html e um array, opicional, onde posso inserir arquivos javascript

```
function getView(url, elementId, array = []) {
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("get", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/html");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept","text/html");
    req.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = this.responseText;

        for(let item of array) {
            insertJS(item);
        }
    };
    req.send();
};

function insertJS(url) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.src = url;
    let element = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(script, element);
};
```

Comment: Se possível poste seu código. Caso esteja utilizando `jQuery`, dê preferência por utilizar o método [**.on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ou então crie uma função para inicializar os efeitos e toda vez que houver uma atualização, basta executar a função criada.

Comment: Acredito que o código não vá influenciar, mas editei. Não uso jQuery.

Comment: Seria bem legal o codigo inteiro, saber de onde vc esta utilizando o material design, se tem algum framework por traz, alguma outra linguagem sendo utilizada em conjunto, como esta iniciando os componentes, mais referencias no geral.

Nao conseguiremos ajudar, pois sua pergunta mostra apendar 2 funções que sem mais contexto nao poderemos ajudar.

Comment: @CaioKoiti não é usado nenhum framework ou biblioteca, e os arquivos do mdl (css e js) estão sendo chamados no head normalmente `<script defer src="..."></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="..">` já tentei sem o defer e com async mas não funcionou

Comment: Tente chamando `componentHandler.upgradeDom()` após o Ajax inserir novos elementos na página.

Comment: @dvd funcionou! Adiciona uma resposta ai rapidão pra que possa aceitar e recompensar. Porém ao usar essa função todo a página é rerenderizada né?

Comment: Resposta postada. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chame a função `componentHandler.upgradeDom()` após o Ajax adicionar novos elementos ao DOM. Isso irá atualizar o DOM no Material Design.

Comment: Sabe dizer se isso recarrega todo o DOM ou apenas o que foi modificado pela função?

Comment: Provavelmente todo o DOM. Ao meu ver não tem como saber o que foi modificado.

Comment: Depois vou dar uma olhada na documentação, valeu